# Plot multiple parameters in subplots using for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, plot

I want to do a figure with 4 plots, using par(mfrow=c(2,2)). I have managed to do this in a loop. But - next step is to add a second parameter (time series) in each of these "subplots". The result should be 4 plots with 2 time series each and with different colors. I just cant make this work!!! My result is 4 plots with only the last time series (depth) in it. I have tried par(new=true) but it won´t work. Please help anyone?

```
toplot <- cbind(ox_s, AOU, ox_sat, o2) # My data, 4 parameters
D = c(40,50)                           # 2 depths I want to plot the data from
nr_col = length(D)                     
myColorMap = rainbow(nr_col)           # to use different colours for different depths

par(mfrow=c(2,2))                      # setting up 4 plots

for (j in 1:length(D)){                # looping over depths
index = which(my_depth == D[j])        # finding rows for my depths
for (k in 1:ncol(toplot)){             # looping over parameters
plot(as.Date(my_time[index]),toplot[index,k], type = "b", 
xlim = range(st,en),col = myColorMap[j])
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reverse the order of the loops?  i.e. do both parts for the 1st plot (plot, then use `lines` or `points` to add to the plot), then move onto the 2nd plot, etc.  This will probably be the simplest.

The other option if you feel you really need to do all the initial plots first, then go back and add to them, is to save the graphical parameters after each plot, then the 2nd time through use `par(mfg=...` to reselect a plot, reset the graphical parameters to what they were, then add to the plot.

You might also want to look at the `matplot` function or check into the ggplot2 or lattice packages for other ways to create faceted plots with multiple lines within the plot.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked when I used both plot and points commands. Thanks for the help!
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) 
indexD = which(my_depth == D[1])
for (k in 1:ncol(toplot)){
for (j in 2:length(D)){
     plot(as.Date(my_time[indexD]),toplot[indexD,k], type = "b", 
     xlim = range(st,en),col = myColorMap[1])
     index = which(my_depth == D[j])
     points(as.Date(my_time[index]),toplot[index,k], type = "b", 
     xlim = range(st,en),col = myColorMap[j], ylab = j)
}
}